# How to detect Flash full screen mode and escape from it with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flash, fullscreen

I need a way to send notification to the browser that my website user has entered full screen mode in Flash. On clicking a link running only JavaScript within flash it escapes full screen and completes the rest of the JavaScript.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.viewpoint.com/dc/PropertiesandFunction.html

```
Name: **FullScreen** 
Mode: **R**      
Type: **boolean**    
Default: **false**  
Description: **Whether the Animator is currently in full-screen mode.**
```